# Angualr2: component is not a known element?

Tags: javascript, angular, module, components

Have a component called "card" and use a lot during application, so I decided to leave it available in any application importing in **app.module**

Tried in two ways:
1-Importing **card.component** into declarations after AppComponent.
2-I transformed the card into module and imported into imports.

In none of the cases solved the problem, the error persists.
"card is not a known element"

Obs: In situation 2, yes I export the component within the card. Module

Codes...

Situation 1 (declarations):

```
// app.module.ts
import { CardComponent } from './components/card/card.component'; 
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CardComponent
  ],
```

Situation 2 (import module):

```
// app.module.ts
import { CardModule } from './components/card/card.module';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CardModule,
```

Card codes

```
// card.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}

// card.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CardComponent } from './card.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CardComponent],
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  exports: [CardComponent],
  providers: [],
})
export class CardModule {}
```

Comment: How are you using it in your template?

Comment: Hey @yoonjesung... simple

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: your selector is card, so you should be using it as <card></card>

Comment: ....! Yeah, iam using tag <card>, the error is 'card' is not a known element:

Comment: It doesn't make any sense the error :(

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for you but I created a plunkr with a working sample. Perhaps you can take a look at the settings and see if there is something missing: https://embed.plnkr.co/EUreWgDXN9fliD6G00gp/

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that if you're trying to use this `CardComponent` or `CardModule` in other Modules, not only the main `AppModule`, you must import it in the Modules you want to use them. I suggest you to insert the `CardComponent` or import the `CardModule` into a `SharedModule` that will be imported in all your Modules.

Example:

First you create your `CardModule` declaring your `CardComponent`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [CardComponent]
})
export class CardModule {}
```

If you don't have a `SharedModule` yet, it's a good practice to create one and use it to import/export common shared modules abroad the whole application.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CardModule,
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    CardModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Then you can import your `SharedModule` into your `AppModule`, so your components declared into it can use everything you shared in the `SharedModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    SharedModule
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And importing the `SharedModule` into any other feature module will give it all basics imports your modules need.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
  ...
})
export class FeatureModule {}
```

Be aware that you should create a static method `forRoot` in your `SharedModule` if you want to provide any `Singleton` service by it. Then when importing the `SharedModule` into your `AppModule` you import it calling the `.forRoot()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

But it was all the same, put in the SharedModule or use direct the CardModule The problem consists of the same.

What in fact I need is, leave the CardModule available in every application from the AppModule.

I don't see the advantage in every route I'm going to use is importing the CardModule.

For example, there is a plugin called NG-bootstrap, it is imported into the AppModule and is available in every application, that's what I need to do.

Comment: @KevenJesus if you see the getting started page from ng-bootstrap you see that you have to import the .forRoot() method into the main AppModule and import the NgbModule normally in other modules. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Comment: Yes I saw, exactly I would like my CardModule had the same behavior as NG-Bootstrap. I used it just for example.

Comment: @KevenJesus you didn't understand. The NG-bootstrap you are talking about says in it's getting started page that you HAVE to import it's NgbModule in EVERY module you want to use it.

Comment: Ok, But I care it just in appModule and I can access any other part of the application, that's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: I would like to do the same with my CardModule, leave it accessible in every application importing only in the AppModule